# YearWise Categorywise Post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Please help me to display yearwise as categorywise post using as custom post type and custom taxonomies category name

like eg:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], then please return and file an [edit] and add all relevant code and info you might have regarding this issue. We expect that you have at least tried something to solve this. It is a huge plus (*actually a must*) if you can share your code and explain where you are failing. This helps someone to directly answer your specific issue :-)

Comment: I dont understand how to start this type to display in wordpress.

Comment: I have created as custom post type naming as film_video and also created as taxonomies name as film_category which will be added as hindi,english,tamil (is different languages which show as video)